# Ignoring strings in a list using regular expressions in python

Tags: python, list

I am fetching some information from the sites and for example i am fetching address of some customers

```
address = ['Mr Thomas',
 '+(91)-9849633132, 9959455935',
 '+(91)-9849633132',
 '9196358485',
 '8846853128',
 '8-4-236/2']
```

From the above list i want to ignore strings starting with `+(91) and 9 and 8` which are nothing but the phone numbers, so i used regular expressions as below

```
import re


result = [i for i in address if not re.match(r"[98]\B", i)]
```

**result**

```
['Mr Thomas','+(91)-9849633132, 9959455935','+(91)-9849633132','8-4-236/2']
```

That is the strings starting with `9 and 8` are ignored but i want to ignore the strings starting with `+(91)` too , can anyone please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add in another check for the +(91), using the | (or) operator. Like so:

```
>>> [i for i in address if not re.match(r"[98]\B|\+\(91\)\B", i)]
['Mr Thomas', '8-4-236/2']
```

Note that you have to escape +, (, and ) because those are special characters.

As an aside, it might be more efficient to use a filter, rather than a list comprehension:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: not re.match(r"[98]\B|\+\(91\)\B", x), address)
['Mr Thomas', '8-4-236/2']
```

Though I can't be sure.

Edit: Looks like it's not more efficient. However, I find it to be more self documenting, but you can take it as you will.

Comment: I was just running `timeit` when you edited - regardless, any performance difference would be implementation-dependent, and this would probably be premature optimisation anyway.  If performance was a problem, using `re.compile` might be a more fruitful optimisation.

Comment: @James I mostly just meant it as a second option. Thank you for confirming though.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [i for i in address if not re.match(r"\+[98]\B", i)]
```

Comment: Thats not working actually and i am getting the same result

Comment: @shivakrishna That should actually give you a result that doesn't match any of the strings in your list.

Answer (score 0):

This does work:

```
 result = [i for i in s if not re.match(r'[+89][-()+0-9/\s]+',i)]
```

Why? The '\B' switch is detrimental here as the match MUST NOT occur at the beginning of the string.
Additionally, the proposed search pattern allows for white space within the numbers.